# Jquery - Append vs AppendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendto

Can somebody explain me why regular Append into a loop works better than AppendTo?

```
//Using Regular Append
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
$("#myDiv").empty().append(ul)

$.each(movies, function (count, item) {
    var id = 'li_' + count;
    ul.append('<li id=' + id + '>' + item + '</li>');

    $('#' + id).click(function () { });
});

//Using AppendTo
var div = $("#myDiv").empty(),
    ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo(div);

$.each(movies, function (count, item) {
    $('<li>' + item + '</li>').click(function () { }).appendTo(ul);
});
```

Result
http://jsperf.com/sdp-jquery-append/3

Comment: Some faster options added: http://jsperf.com/sdp-jquery-append/4

Comment: Just a sidenote: When you're using `append`, you're appending a string. When you're using `appendTo` you're appending a jQuery object. `append` is still slightly faster, but the performance difference is a lot less when using `append` with a jQuery object (http://jsperf.com/sdp-jquery-append/6). I'd guess that there are some additional overheads when using `appendTo` as you're creating the object first, and then calling methods on that object, rather than selecting a cached object, and appending to it.

Answer (score 1):

**append vs appendTo performance (jQuery 1.9.1)**

From what can be seen in jQuery code, one of the reasons appendTo has better performance, is because appendTo implementation is slightly more complicated than regular append.

While append depends roughly on native appendChild function, appendTo is a jQuery addition which needed to be handled by code (there's additional loop inside appendTo which operates on elements and actually calls .append again). While the performance hit isn't big (if you just compare simplest usage, like in this example: http://jsperf.com/sdp-jquery-append/5), it certainly is something to keep in mind.

**As to example labeled "Better" in linked jsperf:**

It performs better, because in fastest version (in jsperf you linked to) you just collect html to be appended, instead of actually appending it on every iteration.

It saves browser resources, since it don't have to reflow and repaint the content on every iteration.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean because both appends are into a 'each' loop, and also in the first version the browser needs to select the node again, instead use the "cached" element return by appendTo

Comment: the samples you added are better, but my question is about the difference between $.append and $.appendTo

Comment: Btw there's an even faster solution without using the jQuery each loop but native for: http://jsperf.com/sdp-jquery-append/7

Comment: @Simon Yep, exactly. jQuery.each is slooow when compared to vanilla javascript loop.

Answer (score -1):

`append(content)` appends content to the inside of every matched element.

`appendTo(selector)` appends all of the matched elements to another specified set of elements.