# jQuery.remove() deleting the wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a nutrition label just like this: [Example](https://juicerecipes.com/build/)

Currently have my db all set up. I am trying to get it to work one thing at the moment and then can do it with the rest.

My db looks like:

```
ingName: ....
fat: ... 
carbs ... etc
```

The problem I am having right now is huge. I have been stuck on it for the last 3 days and no one seems to know what is wrong. I have a cross by ever div which is created so that the user can delete that ingredient he has added. So if they have:

```
Apple : 1g
Mango : 2g 
Melon: 3g 
Total : 6g
```

Lets say they dont want mango anymore then it should look like:

```
Apple: 1g
Mango: 2g
Total: 3g
```

However I cant to get that to work. Every time I click on the cross, it deletes everything and leaves nothing.

HTML:

```
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
      <b>Total Fat</b>
     <span id="fat">0.0</span>
    </th>
    <td>
      <b>22%</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
<input type="text" name='search_term' id="search_term" class="searchFunction">
<input id="addButton" type="button" value="Add">
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="result"></ul>
</div>
<div class="selectedStuff"></div>
```

My live site:

http://diet.elementalbydesign.com/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/build.php

Edit: Now you see guys how it only takes away -1 every time I delete a div rather than the ammount I have set up in the database? This is the big part of the problem which I am stuck on.

Comment: If I were you, I would reduce my code into more manageable and modular functions so I could evaluate the integrity of each moving piece; it all boils down to managing a collection of data and pieces of state.

Comment: @nocarrier i am not the best of this, and i been sturggling for a couple of days now so i will try that

Comment: We all have to learn somehow :)

Comment: Ah so fat people are helping below :) getting there slowly @nocarrier

Comment: Still nothing :( not subtracting at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this how you display the selected ingredients?

```
"<div>" + searchedValue + "<span data-fat='"+data+"' data-itemfat='"+data+"'>X</span></div>"
```

Fix first the returned data from `build.php`, because for example, when Banana is selected, it returns `<script>$(" #fat').html(3);<="" script="">4'` that is why it displays `4' data-itemfat='4'>X`. Make sure that it only returns the `id` of the ingredient! No HTML elements or whatsoever.

Not sure if [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) is the right choice for displaying the data, but I would recommend you try [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Read more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333899/jquery-append-vs-appendto). And we will add a `class` tag for your `<span>` in order to label them:

```
divHolder.append('<div style="background-color: yellow;
                              width: 700px;
                              margin-top: 10px;
                              border-style: solid;
                              border-color: #0000ff">' + searchedValue + '
                      <span data-fat="'+data+'" data-itemfat="'+data+'" class="ingredient">X</span>
                  </div>');
```

Then, your script to remove the ingredient:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ingredient", function(){

    var curr_fat = parseInt($("#fat").html()), /* GET THE CURRENT FAT */
        toberemovedfat = parseInt($(this).attr('data-fat')); /* GET THE FAT OF THE 'TO BE REMOVED' INGREDIENT */
    curr_fat = curr_fat - toberemovedfat; /* GET THE DIFFERENCE */
    $("#fat").html(curr_fat); /* DISPLAY THE NEW FAT */
    $(this).remove(); /* REMOVE THE DISPLAY OF REMOVED INGREDIENT */

});
```

Comment: ah i have tried this :( and this has not worked, this question is driving me and a lot of people crazy :) there seems to be no one that can fix it when it comes to subtracting, i uploaded my site live if u wanted to see it , if it helps in anyway

Comment: You tried this? But I think you should first fix the display when an ingredient is selected, it shows `1' data-itemfat='1'>X`. The `data` from `build.php` escapes the html and that results to that display.

Comment: Ah yes my friend was trying something and it did not work , could you please the exact code u want me to try just in case i am writting it wrong

Comment: You just have to assign a `class` tag for your `span` of your `X`. Then add the script that I made inside your `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Sorry logan were does this go? <span data-fat='"+data+"' data-itemfat='"+data+"' class="ingredient"> i dont really understand

Comment: If you see the answer below i got the divs to delete 1 by 1 which is great, but the class on the right hand side inside the label , the number goes blank for some reason

Comment: @Nevershow2016 - it is inside your javascript. After the `data` returns from `build.php`. You just have to add exactly this `class="ingredient"`, that line only to your `<span>`.

Comment: Just tried it now :( no luck again, does the same thing as the guy below, will delete 1 by 1 , but on the label the fat does not subtract

Comment: @Nevershow2016 - see my updated answer. It will reduce the fat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106964/discussion-between-nevershow2016-and-logan-wayne).

Comment: Still nothing logan :( makes it go blank

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).remove();
```

You are deleting everything because "this" refers to ".selectedStuff" which is the div containing everything.

You need to use a delegated event instead:

```
$(".selectedStuff").on("click", "span", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Try that. It will delegate the events to any span element contained in the .selectedStuff div. It would be better to give your "X" span a class like `<span class="deleteButton">X</span>` to make this work better, then you could use:

```
$(".selectedStuff").on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Ah i have got rid of that, however now the div it self wont remove and also the fat content being held the number inside of that disappears

Comment: That is my site , can you see what i mean ?

Comment: What does your console say when you click the span? any errors?

Comment: You removed $(this).remove() instead of moving it to the proper place.

Comment: were should i move it?

Comment: Thanks dexter i actualyl got to work but the problem is its that its not working on the label side, every time i take it away it delete 1 fat instead of the amount

Comment: http://diet.elementalbydesign.com/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/build.php there it is in action

Comment: So if u try and add banana which has 4 fat, it will only take away 1 fat instead of 4

Comment: Sorry, forgot to type the "parent()" part when pasting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106967/discussion-between-nevershow2016-and-dexter).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are selecting the container div and not the items in your event handler.

```
$('.selectedStuff').on("click", function(){

                        $(this).remove();
                    });
```

This will remove the outer div.

You are better off doing it like this.

```
$('.selectedStuff').on("click", 'span', function(){

                        $(this).closest('div').remove();
                    });
```

Which will remove the closest div element when you click on the span in the .selectedStuff element.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah that has got the divs to be removed 1 by 1 :) which is great but the number on the right in my label still goes blank

Comment: this is because of the way you are assigning and retreiving the data. Try `$('.selectedStuff span').data('fat');`
And see what you get.
When you create the line, use `$('<span>X</span> ').data('fat', 1);`
And then look at `$('.selectedStuff').data('fat');`

Answer (score 0):

if problem persists.... than consider .... [Shouting Code](http://code.shouttoday.com).I found there good explanation

- This is because Jquery Click function misbehave for dynamic added data because these references had not present in DOM.

Solution:-

Just call a method on click of span
like that

```
<div>" + searchedValue + "<span onclick="removeStuff(this);" "data-fat='"+data+"' data-itemfat='"+data+"'>X</span></div>
```

a method that can remove you element

```
 function removeStuff(thisVar)
{
    $(thisVar).parents('.selectedStuff').remove();
}
```